# Asyncore TCP server can't print the socket info

Tags: python-2.7

I've tried to write an asyncore server to handle with phone and chip.

I tried to identify which connection is for chip or phone by recognizing the messages string sent by them. If the chip say " help, too much water ", server send message "too much water" to phone.

```
class RequestHandler(asyncore.dispatcher):
  def __init__(self, sock, q, addr):
    self.sock = sock
    self.q = q

  def handle_read(self, sock):
    self.q = q
    c = self.sock.recv(1024).rstrip('\n')
    c2 = c.rstrip()
    comment = c2.split(',')
    if comment[2] == "chip":    # To identify chip or phone
        self.chip = self.sock
        print("chip is "+str(tuple(addr)))
        if commentTable[comment[0]] == 7:  
            self.comment = 7
            self.q.put(msgTable[int(comment[1])])
        else:
            self.comment = commentTable[comment[0]]

    else:
        self.android = self.sock
        print("android is"+str(tuple(addr)))

  def handle_write(self):
    if self.q.empty():
        if self.comment == 0:
            self.android.send("time,"+"pH,"+"waterlevel,"+"light"+"video")
    else:
        while not self.q.empty():
            self.sock.send(self.q.get())
```

The result of the program is that server does not send the message to anyone.

server:

```
Binding on port = 5000
Connect with('192.168.0.121', 47082)
Connect with('192.168.0.121', 47084)
.....
```

phone:

```
$ ./client 192.168.0.121 5000
Please enter the message: state,
```

It didn't print the info of the phone or chip.

---

Sorry, I forgot to paste my code about class for server.

```
class server_socket(asyncore.dispatcher):
  def __init__(self, host, port):
    asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
    self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.set_reuse_addr()
    self.bind((host, port))
    self.listen(5)
    print("Binding on port = 5000")

  def handle_accept(self):
    pair = self.accept()
    if pair is not None:
        sock, addr = pair
        print("Connect with" + str(tuple(addr)))
        handler = RequestHandler(sock, queue, addr)
```

Comment: Where does the value of `addr` come from? It is not shown in the code.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to paste the code of the other class.